# Counting number of unique values in subset of sorted array

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, structured-array

I have two numpy arrays, `users` and `dat`. For each user in `users` I need to find the data related to the user in `dat` and count the number of unique values. I need to process a case where `len(users)=200000` and `len(dat)=2800000`. Currently I am not exploiting the fact that `dat` is sorted, making the method very slow. How do I do this?

The value 'other' in `dat` merely shows that other values will be present in the structured array as well.

```
import numpy as np

users = np.array([111, 222, 333])
info = np.zeros(len(users))
dt = [('id', np.int32), ('group', np.int16), ('other', np.float)]
dat = np.array([(111, 1, 0.0), (111, 3, 0.0), (111, 2, 0.0), (111, 1, 0.0),
               (222, 1, 0.0), (222, 1, 0.0), (222, 4, 0.0),
               (333, 2, 0.0), (333, 1, 0.0), (333, 2, 0.0)],
               dtype=dt)

for i, u in enumerate(users):
    u_dat = dat[np.in1d(dat['id'], u)]
    uniq = set(u_dat['group'])
    info[i] = int(len(uniq))

print info
```

Comment: In C, you loop and increment your counter when current value != previous value.  This probably isn't helpful here, since looping array elements in python is generally not how you write fast numpy code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to profit from numpy's vectorization, it would help greatly if you could remove all duplicates from `dat` before hand. You can then find the first and last occurrence of a value with two calls to `searchsorted`:

```
dat_unq = np.unique(dat)
first = dat_unq['id'].searchsorted(users, side='left')
last =  dat_unq['id'].searchsorted(users, side='right')
info = last - first
```

This will only be advantageous if you are going to search for a lot of the entries in `dat`. If it is a smaller fraction, you can still use the two calls to `searchsorted` to figure out which slices to call `unique` on:

```
info = np.empty_like(users, dtype=np.intp)
first = dat['id'].searchsorted(users, side='left')
last =  dat['id'].searchsorted(users, side='right')
for idx, (start, stop) in enumerate(zip(first, last)):
    info[idx] = len(np.unique(dat[start:stop]))
```